# Can I give column type as string for serializing as Array in Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model

```
class News < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :types, Array
end
```

My Migration is

```
create_table "news"  do |t|
   t.string     "types"
end
```

Usually we are giving

```
t.text  "types"
```

But here only 3 types are there. So I need mysql to be allocated small space for types. So can I give

```
t.string     "types"
```

or some limit
for an array serialize ?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565557/rails-serialize-value-as-comma-seperated-and-not-as-yaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To a first order, based on some limited tests, yes, you can use `string` instead of `text` as a schema type for `serialized` attributes.