# Rails multi-array format in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ruby-on-rails

Have an old project that someone did in PHP and am attempting to convert it over to Rails. Am encountering an issue when trying to iterate through a multiple array in rails.
The array as stored in the DB looks like this:

`a:5:{i:0;s:8:"Director";i:1;s:11:"Shareholder";i:2;s:14:"Vice President";i:3;s:9:"Secretary";i:4;s:9:"Treasurer";}`

Am trying to display the String values such as "Director" and "Shareholder".
Does the DB field need to be changed to a different format to work?
How would this be done in rails?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did that come from PHP's [`serialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)?

Comment: Not sure. The original code used to create the records is no longer available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like the output of PHP's [`serialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) function to me.

If you have PHP around or don't mind installing it to help with the data migration, then I'd write a short PHP script to convert those columns to JSON using PHP's [`unserialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) and [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) functions: read a value, `unserialize` it, `json_encode` the result, write it back into the database (all in PHP).

After that, you should be able to use ActiveRecord's [`serialize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-serialize) with [JSON as the storage format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6971678/479863):

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :whatever_it_is_called, JSON
end
```

You could also use YAML (the default for ActiveRecord's `serialize`) if you had YAML support in PHP-land.

If you don't want to touch PHP at all, then you'll have to write Ruby parser for PHP's `serialize` format (which seems to be well documented in the PHP docs) and hook that up to ActiveRecord's `serialize`.

You will of course be working with a copy of the real database for all this work.