# Rails Serialize: From YAML to JSON - Getting "unexpected token" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, facebook, serialization, yaml

I used to have the following code to save an array of "friends" IDs (the Facebook User IDs imported via the Graph API and Omniauth) to a User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    serialize :friends


    def self.from_omniauth(auth)

    require 'net/http'
    require 'json'

    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid, :email, :image)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
     user.provider = auth.provider
     user.uid = auth.uid
     user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token

    friendsInfo = Net::HTTP.get(URI("https://graph.facebook.com/" + auth.uid + "/friends?fields=installed&access_token=" + user.oauth_token))
     unless friendsInfo == nil
       friendsData = (JSON.parse(friendsInfo))["data"]
       fArr = []
       friendsData.each do |fD|
        if fD["installed"] == true
         fArr.push(fD["id"])
        end
       end
     end

   user.friends = fArr

   user.save!

  end
end
```

This code saves the User IDs of Facebook friends who also have the app installed to an array, i.e. `["3232344", "2342434", "8738453"]`.

However, I decided to change `serialize :friends` to `serialize :friends, JSON` for security issues, as per [CodeClimate's advice](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2013/03/27/rails-insecure-defaults/), but now it either:

a) saves it all as one JSON string (if there are multiple "friends"), or

b) gives a `795: unexpected token at ''[user ID here]' - ---'` error if there is just one "friend" who also has app installed.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6971678/2445163) has a comment asking how to make this work in Rails 4, so I'm guessing simply adding `JSON` worked in Rails 3.1 but doesn't any more? I've tried variations of `to_json`, `ActiveSupport::JSON.decode`, etc., and writing a [custom serializer](http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-write-custom-serializer-for-activerecord-number-serialize/), but my guess is my error is something to do with serializing after creating the array in my current code? Is a callback the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I found this think that i think that it could help [Converting Serialized YAML to Serialized JSON in Rails models](https://gist.github.com/danielevans/2884087)

I am not seeing where you are calling a YAML or getting one from your code.

but here is the magic line `YAML.load(medium.send(:attribute, :payload)).to_json`

I hope that this help.

Comment: Thanks for this, but what I ended up doing was this: `friendsData = (ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(friendsInfo))["data"]`