# input must be a string or IO - JSON serialize error rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model object User which has a JSON(mysql 5.7 JSON column too) column in it. My model object looks like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 

    after_initialize :set_defaults
    serialize :group_condition, JSON

    def set_defaults
      self.group_condition ||= []
    end

end
```

When I create a new object using User.new, when set_defaults is called, I am getting this error.  `input must be a string or IO`
During the initialization of User object group_condition is null and it will be added with user given input later on. But, Coz of `input must be a string or IO` error I am not able to proceed.
Any Help will be much appreciated

Edit 1:
I am using rails 3.2.22

Comment: Does changing `self.group_condition ||= '[]'` work?

Comment: @mikwat, its also not working.

Comment: Actually, assuming you're using MySQL 5.7.8 or greater, there should be no need to use `serialize`. Try removing that line.

Comment: @mikwat, I am using rails 3.2.22, thats why I am using `serialize`

Comment: Ah, my bad. Maybe related to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080347/activerecord-serialize-using-json-instead-of-yaml